# Regex to pull out square brackets in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Given...

```
var parts = 'value[1]'.split(/\[\]/);
```

What is the regex to have...

```
parts[0] === 'value';
parts[1] === '1';
```

The regex I have above doesn't work.

Comment: Why split? `parts = s.match(/(\w+)\[(\d+)]/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is matching only when '[' is followed by ']'.
You want to use an "or":

```
var parts = 'value[1]'.split(/\[|\]/);
```

Tip: I use https://regex101.com/ which is very good to explain what the regex is matching in detail. Or, for .NET: http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `match` for this:

```
match = 'value[1]'.match(/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/)
match[1] // "value"
match[2] // "1"
```

The match here will match any word characters (`\w+`), followed by  a `[`, then any number of digits (`\d+`), followed by a `]`.